# How to select specific XML child with a given attribute in C# Dataset / Dataview

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dataset, dataview

I have this code which gets all nodes in a simple XML with structure like:

**XML:**

```
<parent>
    <child>
    </child>
</parent>
```

**Code:**

```
private DataView dataGet() {
    DataView functionReturnValue = null;

    DataSet dsListing = new DataSet();
    dsListing.ReadXml(MapPath("~/pathToXml.xml"));
    DataView dvListing = dsListing.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    functionReturnValue = dvListing;

    return functionReturnValue;
    //This returns all child and I need 
}
```

I used to use XPath in different code pieces to select more deep nodes with attributes like:

```
 xmlSource.XPath = "parent/child/node[@id='" + Convert.ToString(CategoryID) + "']/DeepNode";
```

OR

```
 xmlSource.XPath = "parent/child/node[@attribute='True']";
```

**How to select specific XML node with a given attribute from xml like the following to dataGet() above:**

```
<parent>
    <child> 
        <node id="1" attribute="True">
        </node >
        <node id="2" attribute="False">
        </node >
    </child>
</parent>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the examples you gave?

Comment: the dataset read doesn't not work well when the number of level of tags are too large.  The results get put into fragmented tables that cannot get combined easily.  In you case table 0 has just the child element with no rows.  You node rows are in table[1] (not zero).

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, how to call the attr=True then?

Comment: Actually my second issue is that my XML has many "level 2" children  like parent > child > news and parent > child2 > news hence I will want to call each one according page / control.

Comment: It is better to use XmlDocument or XDocument (xml linq) when dataset starts to fragment the results.